# provider can't rebuild main screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
              value: Auth(),
             // value: Auth(),
            ),
            ),
          ],
          child: MaterialApp(
            home: Consumer<Auth>(builder: (ctx, auth, _) {
              return auth.isAuth
                  ? ProfileScreen()
                  : LoginScreen()
            }),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

In this code if isAuth property is changed in auth provider and notifyListeners() is called,My App screen doen't listen to it! what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

`MyApp` won't listen to it because you're not using `Provider.of(context)` inside `build()` method. In your current code, `Consumer`'s `builder` method will be called every time the value is changed.

Comment: If you're asking me to edit your code, then I think I didn't get you right, I'd like you to put `print` statement in 2 places, first inside your `build` method and second inside `builder`, let me know which of them is getting called after your value is changed.

Comment: Both aren't called

Comment: OK, that means your `Auth` isn't changing.

Comment: but when I make hotreload,builder is called and I see the change

Comment: This means you're not correctly using `notifyListeners` inside your `Auth`

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
providers: [ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => Auth())],
```